# Is this a typo, or something I don't understand?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[Might be typos...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kWbf.png)

I'm being asked to find kernel, range, and nullity; there's nothing wrong with that, I know how to do it. But I'm at my wits' end with the meaning of the ones I highlighted in yellow. As far as I understand, the 2) should be $\mathfrak{R}^1 \to \mathfrak{R}^2$, the 4) $\mathfrak{R}^2 \to \mathfrak{R}^1$, and the five $\mathfrak{R}^4 \to \mathfrak{R}^2$.

I can't find an explanation, so I'm thinking that either I don't actually know about this stuff, or these are typos. Are these typos, or things that somehow make sense?

I also have another question that doesn't deserve its own post.

[True or false question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLBIg.png)

The image says: "There's a linear map $\mathfrak{R}^5 \to \mathfrak{R}^5$ with $\rho(T) = \nu(T)$"; Am I right to assume that $\rho(T)$ is the characteristic polynomial, and $\nu(T)$ the minimal polynomial? In that case, my research shows that the answer is true, but what I want to know is if I've got the meanings of $\rho(T)$ and $\nu(T)$ right.

Comment: You are right about the typos. I can't answer the second question from the context.

Comment: @HowDoIMath That's a great thing to know, even if I still don't know about the other one, this helps a lot. Thanks for your kind reply good sir.